# Updating tags after answer is provided

Tags: discussion

When answering a question on SFSE one might not be aware of exactly what tags are provided on the question, before after posting the answer. If a tag is added, after the answer is placed, will it still contribute to vote count for that specific tag? Or does the count happen the second one's answer is posted, hence only taking those tags into account which were on the question at that particular moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag totals remain up to date. If you add a tag to a post with votes, they will aggregate to its totals.